# URL regex to block games, nsfw, music etc

Tags: regex, proxy, filtering

I am looking for a regexp that will block content that is not appropriate for the workplace. This would include keywords like game, games, music, porn, gambling etc etc.

I was going to create one from scratch, but I figured that this is a common requirement and there must be an broad solution out there somewhere. Does anyone know of a good regexp to accomplish this?

I've searched on Google but I mainly get results for validating correct URLs.

ex.
regex:
game(s)?|music|facebook.*?appcenter|porn|youtube| ....

Comment: considered a whitelist instead?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. Blocking URLs with regexes is certain to create hard to track down issues.

Comment: As mccainz suggests, a whitelist would be a much better solution. A regex is too easily circumvented (accessing the IP address directly, proxies, etc) and is likely to trigger false positives too.

Comment: @mccainz Would a whitelist be ideal for a situation where I will allow access to all of the features in Facebook, except for the games section?

Comment: If the games section can be uniquely distinguished from the main facebook path you wish to whitelist then yes.

Comment: @mccainz I guess my concern is that there will be a lot of facebook paths that I wish to allow, and really only one path that I want to block. To me this seems like whitelisting will be a lot more work than blacklisting.